# Spanish idiom for "to stick together"

Tags: modismos

In the sense of giving mutual support to achieve a goal: "If we're going to defeat the enemy, we have to stick together"

Comment: Simply «mantenernos unidos»

Comment: No separarnos. Note: stick together is not formal register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles/stick-together

> If people **stick together**, they stay with each other and support each other.
> e.g. If we all stick together, we ought to be okay.

> Si queremos combatir a (el/la) x **tenemos** que mantenernos unidos.

The present tense is used to describe sth that is happening right now.

> Si queremos combatir a (el/la) x **tendremos** que mantenernos unidos.

We use the future simple to talk about actions happening in the future.

It's an if-then proposition that talks about a likely situation: if sth happens, then sth else happens.

https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/stick%20together

> (to support each other)
> a. mantenerse unidos

> In the sense of giving mutual support to achieve a goal:
> "If we're going to defeat the enemy, we have to stick together"

> "Para vencer **debemos** permanecer unidos"
> (Expressing obligation and duty with regard to oneself and others)

The first variant is a literal translation "In order to defeat your enemy, you must act together with other partners." If you join forces with someone, you stick together in order to achieve a common purpose (as a common front in your battle against the enemy)

> "Para vencer debiéramos(imperfect subjunctive)/deberíamos(conditional simple tense)/debíamos(imperfect past) permanecer unidos"(depending on the context)

In this case, however, they should unite their forces in a common struggle against their common enemy.

> 'Unidos venceremos, divididos fracasaremos' / 'Unidos venceremos divididos caemos' / 'Unidos jamás seremos vencidos' / 'Un grupo dividido no se sostiene"("United we stand, divided we fall") / ¡Existimos porque resistimos! / ¡Juntos podemos vencer!

This is a slogan for resistance.

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/unity

https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/paremia/pdf/010/004_alvarez.pdf

> Nación dividida, nación destruida. / Pueblo dividido, cátalo vencido. / Reino dividido, reino perdido.